# RestKit ObjectMapping 2.0 tutorial needed

Tags: restkit

I'm new to RestKit and I'm looking for a good tutorial on ObjectMapping2.0. **Note the 2.0 there**, Blake's [wonderful tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/) are dated. Googling isn't finding me anything. Have you come across one? Please share it. Thanks.

Comment: NOT a dupe, this was posted back in 2011...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend the [Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) guide in RestKit github - this doc is usually the most up-to-date thing you can find. My apologies if you already seen that one.

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping) is the current one

Answer (score 5):

Check this awesome tutorial for RestKit using blocks from Taras Kalapun!

[How I Restkit](http://kalapun.com/blog/2012/05/17/how-i-restkit/)

Is just great.

Comment: Wonderful, although it's for 0.10.0

Comment: Well, the question was edited, originally the author was asking for 0.10. My answer is from May 2012, way before RestKit 0.20 was released.

Answer (score 4):

http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKObjectManager.html

RestKit v0.20.0(the latest version now) is much different than previous versions. this reference is mainly talking about RKObjectManager, but you will understand how to use main features of RestKit v0.20.0 by reading it. of course including how to map.

Comment: Thanks for the update. And also note, that ObjectMapping 2.0 is different from RestKit v0.20.0.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping this link helps for better understanding of restkit object mapping